# COM: If I change the parent of an Interface do I need to create a new Interface?

Tags: c++, com, c++builder

I have been adding new functionality to a COM Interface, and from what I have read the only way to do it( and keep it backwards compatible ) is to create a new interface that inherits the old interface and add the new methods. I have tried doing this but my hierarchy is already quite complex.

Say this is how my interfaces currently are:

```
IBaseInterface
    |
IDerivedInterface
```

and I want to add some functionality to the Base Interface, and it now looks like this:

```
IBaseOldInterface
    |
IBaseInterface
    |
IDerivedInterface
```

because I have added this new functionality do i need to create a new IDerivedInterface? I have tried it the way it is at the moment and it doesn't seem to work properly for all cases.

I just want some confirmation really, and an explanation why if possible

I need to further explain what my ideal situation would be and why:

I want to add some methods to the IBaseInterface class that then all of the derived classes can use. What I thought might be possible is this:

```
                   IBaseOldInterface
                  /                 \
IDerivedOldInterface               IBaseNewInterface
                   \               /
                  IDerivedNewInterface
```

I understand that Diamond Inheritance should be avoided but they are only interfaces so I think that will be alright.

having this new structure, when a user requests one of the INewDerivedInterfaces. The query interface will return the correct Interface for that IID, whether that is the INewDerivedInterface or the IOldDerivedInterface.

Comment: It is crucial that you change the IID for the interface.  So you won't have old code that doesn't know anything about the changed interface try to use the new server.  And don't forget that a coclass can implement any number of interfaces, they don't have to inherit from each other.

Comment: I have added further explanation as to what I think would be needed. All the interfaces that are marked with "Old" Still have the same IID's as they did before, only the new Interfaces have new IID's generated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding methods to the base interface (or replacing it by another that extends it) changes the vtable layout of all derived interfaces, so indeed you need to create new derived interfaces with new IIDs.

Comment: Thank you, I think that solves it. It does look like its going to be a lot of work though. I am trying to implement this in a system that already has at least 100 interfaces, which have been changed over time. Up until this point non have been forward or backwards compatible and somehow it has gone unnoticed (or ignored) :)

Answer (score 5):

That does not work. As you have said, to maintain compatibility, you cannot modify an already published interface. But by changing the inheritance you are modifying the interface.

So, you could add the new methods to a new subclass and then you would have this structure:

```
IBaseInterface
    |
IDerivedInterface
    |
IDerivedInterface2
```

Or perhaps what you should do is add a new interface which the implementing objects support. So, instead of using inheritance, you simply declare that you implementing class supports multiple interfaces.

In that case you would leave the existing inheritance structure alone, and have something like this:

```
IBaseInterface         INewInterface
    |
IDerivedInterface
```

and then implement the class like this:

```
class TMyObject: public TInterfacedObject, IDerivedInterface, INewInterface
```

Answer (score 3):

There are three ways you can add new functionality to your `IBaseInterface`, `IDerivedInterface` interfaces:

1. You add new methods to the bottom of `IDerivedInterface`. The newly built apps aware of these new methods will be able to use them. Earlier built apps will keep safely using old methods. You cannot add methods to `IBaseInterface` or reinherit it from another interface because this will shift dependent methods. 
   *From the context of your original question I have a feeling that you are changing public interfaces used by a range of external software items, and you don't want your change to cause any issues. If so, you perhaps would want to restrain from going this path, even though it looks simple and doing the job (see below why).*
2. You can derive new interface from either `IBaseInterface` or `IDerivedInterface` and newly built apps will use it. Beware of necessity to assign new IID to the new interface.
3. You define new interface (such as `INewInterface` in @DavidHeffernan's above) and your COM objects implements just more interfaces. Newly built apps can query new interface and call its methods.

Item 3 above is perhaps the typical, easy and convenient way to extend the object. Item 2 makes sense only if you need to keep methods on "main" interface, e.g. for legacy clients such as VB6. Item 1 is a way to quick add stuff without modifying code too much, it does work too - the only catch is that client won't be able to safely detect whether the server is implementing old methods only, or new ones as well.

Comment: I really don't feel nice about your option 1. I wish you hadn't said it, I can't +1 while it's still there, even though the other points are good.

Comment: @RogerRowland: if this interface is internal, such as not published outside, this is the easiest way. You don't really need to add new interface each time you want to add a new method. The last paragraph explains the catch.

Comment: Yes, I see where you're coming from but if the interface is not yet public all bets are off anyway and the OP could just refactor the whole interface.

Comment: @RogerRowland: This is why I wrote: 3 is typical, 2 is possibly necessary for other reasons, and 1 is tricky and perhaps even not applicable. This still does not make this extensibility method impractical.

Comment: No, and these subsequent comments clarify that. I was just feeling it wasn't visible enough in your answer and I guess I was hoping you'd edit it slightly so I could upvote - perhaps I'm being too pedantic ;-)

Comment: @RogerRowland: That's fine, perhaps the edit makes it more clear to follow your suggestion.

Comment: If I added a new Interface called InterfaceWithNewMethod (rubbish name but bare with me). and I then had both the derived class and the base class inherit from this then won't they both need new interfaces, as their Interface definitions have changed?

Comment: Adding support for new interfaces does not normally affect clients using old interfaces. This works pretty straightforward, so you can add interfaces safely. You don't need to inherit one interface from another - in most cases this is a confusing and unnecessary practice (nevertheless you see a lot of real world examples doing otherwise, sometimes it makes sense), just add new side interface rather than new derived interface.

Answer (score 0):

To add new functionality to `IBaseInterface`, you need to create a new interface, but DO NOT change your existing hierarchy at all.  What you can do instead is have the **class** that implements `IBaseInterface` *also* implement the new interface as well, eg:

```
type
  IBaseInterface = interface
    ...
  end;

  IBaseInterface2 = interface(IBaseInterface)
    ...
  end;

  IDerivedInterface = interface(IBaseInterface)
    ...
  end;

  TBaseClass = class(TInterfacedObject, IBaseInterface, IBaseInterface2)
    ...
  end;

  TDerivedClass = class(TBaseClass, IDerivedInterface)
    ...
  end;
```

That way, any code that wants to use the new `IBaseInterface2` functionality can query any `IBaseInterface` for that interface, and if successful then use the new functionality, eg:

```
var
  Base2: IBaseInterface2;
begin
  if Supports(AnyBaseOrDerivedInterfacePtr, IBaseInterface2, Base2) then
  begin
    // use Base2 as needed...
  end;
end;
```